# Pass array as query parameter in Postman

Tags: arrays, rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to pass an array as query parameter in `Postman`.

I am calling DELETE method to delete a user from list of databases. It is expecting list of database names as array in the query parameter. When I pass as given below, I am getting error.

> {"code":2,"message":"data_services must be an array and not empty"}

[image: Trying to Pass databasenames as array]

Please let me know, how can I pass an array as query parameter in `Postman`.

Comment: Can you post the DELETE method signature/ code?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. I misread the DELETE method. It was expecting array in the content section. I have provided answer for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mis-read the DELETE method. It was expecting array of databases in the body of the Http body section, instead of on query parameter section. I provided the array as given below and it got succeeded.

The below is the way, I passed array to Http request in the body section.

[image: Passing Array in the Http request content body]

Answer (score 26):

You need to create 2 keys with the same name and add postfix `[]`
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can specify the parameter key multiple times with different values.
Don't use square brackets or numbers like an array in code.

This will result in a query string like so:

```
?data_services=somename&data_services=anothername
```

Comment: no. it is not working out. Even if a specify a single value `data_services=DBName`, it is throwing same error

Comment: Sorry for confusion caused. I have upvoted your answer. But, as my problem is different, I have added the answer for clarity

Answer (score 2):

[image]

can you check below link it is useful for you

https://medium.com/@darilldrems/how-to-send-arrays-with-get-or-post-request-in-postman-f87ca70b154e

Comment: I have already tried it. Not working. mine is just list of databasename and not associative array.